# How to fix 'http: named cookie not present' in golang?

Tags: http, go, cookies, jwt, postman

I'm building a small dinner/plan management application (with the use of microservices) for a couple of people I know. The intention is that each person can login to their own account and can then authenticate to other services using a bearer token (JWT).

This bearer token is stored in a cookie. However, I cannot find this cookie after it has been set and I try to retrieve it again.

Which eventually results in the error

```
http: named cookie not present
```

Why is the response body of the request empty? 
Why aren't there any cookies sent with my GET request? 
How can I go about fixing this?

---

I've searched around the net for a bit and tried the following things

- **Net/http cookie**:
  The implementation that seems the most simple, and also the one that I'm showing here. It seems like this trivial example should work.
- **Cookiejar implementation**:
  I tried to use the cookiejar implementation to set and retrieve the cookies from both the browser and postman, however it resulted in the same outcome. The cookiejar implementation I used is described in https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/?m=all#New
- **Setting to specific URL and extra GET request**:
  I tried to place the cookies on a different specific URL within my domain. At some point it seemed like the cookies could only be retrieved from a certain specific absolute URL, this was not the case.
- **httputil DumpRequestOut**:
  I found that the utility package of net/http had a function called DumpRequestOut, this function might have been able to extract the body from the request, but this was also empty.
- **Setting cookie 'secure' flag to false**:
  I found a suggestion that the secure flag makes the cookies impossible to read. Unfortunately changing the secure flag had no effect.

---

Postman clearly shows that the cookies do exist. My browser (firefox) also shows that the cookies exist, but they have been given quite an abstract name.
The Postman requests can be found at https://www.getpostman.com/collections/fccea5d5dc22e7107664

If I try to retrieve the cookies using the "net/http" package from golang, the response body comes up empty.

I set the session tokens and redirect the client directly after I've authenticated the user/password combination.

```golang
// SetTokenAndRedirect sets an access token to the cookies
func SetTokenAndRedirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *mgo.Session, u *user.User, redirectURL string) *handler.AppError {
    // Generate a unique ID for the session token.
    tokenID := uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()).String()
    //set the expiration time (found in config.config.go)
    expirationTime := time.Now().Add(config.ExpireTime)
    // Set the cookie with the JWT
    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     config.AccessTokenName,
        Value:    createToken(u.UserID, expirationTime, tokenID, r.Header.Get("User-Agent")),
        Expires:  expirationTime,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Secure:   false,
    })

    // Redirects user to provided redirect URL
    if redirectURL == "" {
        return handler.AppErrorf(417, nil, "No redirect URL has been provided")
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, 200)
    return nil
}
```

I try to verify the incoming request and JWT token as follows.

```golang
// All handlers will have this adapted serveHTTP function 
func (fn AppHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := Authorize(w, r); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Not Authorized: %v", err), http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }
    if e := fn(w, r); e != nil { // e is *appError, not os.Error.
        log.Printf("Handler error: status code: %d, message: %s, underlying err: %#v",
            e.Code, e.Message, e.Error)

        http.Error(w, e.Message, e.Code)
    }
}
```

```golang
// Claims defines what will be stored in a JWT access token
type Claims struct {
    ProgramVersion string `json:"programVersion"`
    UserAgent      string `json:"userAgent"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

// Authorize checks if the jwt token is valid
func Authorize(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    c, err := r.Cookie("access_token")
    if err != nil {
        if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
            // The program returns this error
            return err
        }
        return err
    }

    tokenString := c.Value

    claim := &Claims{}

    tkn, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, claim, func(tkn *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return config.JwtSigningSecret, nil
    })
    if !tkn.Valid {
        return err
    }
    if err != nil {
        if err == jwt.ErrSignatureInvalid {
            return err
        }
        return err
    }

    // JWT token is valid
    return nil
}
```

---

The request is structured as follows when **setting the cookie**

```sh
// Pretty printed version
Host: localhost:8080
content-type: application/json
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0
cache-control: no-cache
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 68
connection: keep-alive
accept: */*
postman-token: 36268859-a342-4630-9fb4-c286f76d868b
cookie: access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcm9ncmFtVmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMC4wIiwidXNlckFnZW50IjoiUG9zdG1hblJ1bnRpbWUvNy4xMS4wIiwiZXhwIjoxNTU2MjA0MTg3LCJqdGkiOiJlZDlmMThhZi01NTAwLTQ0YTEtYmRkZi02M2E4YWVhM2M0ZDEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTYyMDM1ODcsImlzcyI6ImdrLmp3dC5wcm9maWxlU2VydmljZS5hIn0.bssnjTZ8woKwIncdz_EOwYbCtt9t6V-7PmLxfq7GVyo
```

```sh
// Raw Version
&{POST /auth/users/login?redirect=/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Cache-Control:[no-cache] Postman-Token:[d33a093e-c7ab-4eba-8c1e-914e85a0d289] Cookie:[access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcm9ncmFtVmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMC4wIiwidXNlckFnZW50IjoiUG9zdG1hblJ1bnRpbWUvNy4xMS4wIiwiZXhwIjoxNTU2MjA0NDU4LCJqdGkiOiIzOTk1MmI1NS0yOWQzLTQ4NGQtODhhNC1iMDlhYmI1OWEyNzgiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTYyMDM4NTgsImlzcyI6ImdrLmp3dC5wcm9maWxlU2VydmljZS5hIn0.DFA7KBET3C2q1A9N1hXGMT0QbabHgaVcDBpAYpBdbi8] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] Connection:[keep-alive] Content-Type:[application/json] User-Agent:[PostmanRuntime/7.11.0] Accept:[*/*] Content-Length:[68]] 0xc0001ba140 <nil> 68 [] false localhost:8080 map[redirect:[/]] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:36584 /auth/users/login?redirect=/ <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc00016a2a0}
```

The request is structured as follows when **getting the cookie**

```sh
// Pretty printed version
Host: localhost:8080
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: 20f7584f-b59d-46d8-b50f-7040d9d40062
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
connection: keep-alive
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0
accept: */*
```

```sh
// Raw version
2019/04/25 12:22:56 &{GET /path/provide HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[User-Agent:[PostmanRuntime/7.11.0] Accept:[*/*] Cache-Control:[no-cache] Postman-Token:[b79a73a3-3e08-48a4-b350-6bde4ac38d23] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] Connection:[keep-alive]] {} <nil> 0 [] false localhost:8080 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:35884 /path/provide <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc000138240}
```

The response is structured as follows when **setting the cooke**

```sh
response Headers: map[Location:[/] Set-Cookie:[access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcm9ncmFtVmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMC4wIiwidXNlckFnZW50IjoiR28taHR0cC1jbGllbnQvMS4xIiwiZXhwIjoxNTU2MjI4ODIyLCJqdGkiOiJlY2Q2NWRkZi1jZjViLTQ4N2YtYTNkYy00NmM3N2IyMmUzMWUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTYyMjgyMjIsImlzcyI6ImdrLmp3dC5wcm9maWxlU2VydmljZS5hIn0.0sOvEzQS2gczjWSmtVSD_u0qMV2L7M4hKF1KUM08-bQ; Expires=Thu, 25 Apr 2019 21:47:02 GMT; HttpOnly] Date:[Thu, 25 Apr 2019 21:37:02 GMT] Content-Length:[0]]
```

---

I expect that the Authorize function will return nil. Also,if I add the following piece of code I expect that there are some cookies present.

```golang
for _, cookie := range r.Cookies() {
    fmt.Fprint(w, cookie.Name)
}
```

However, the Authorize function returns the error in the title and the printf does not print out any cookies.

Comment: Please provide the code that sets the cookie, and while you're at it add the response dump so we can see the header.

Comment: "Postman clearly shows that the cookies do exist." can you please export your postman request and share it here as well?

Comment: @NoamHacker, Thank you for the quick reply, I've added the postman request above.

Comment: @mkopriva, Also thanks for the quick reply, I've added the code that sets the cookies as well.

Comment: no problem! could you please paste the contents of the request here? also, I didn't see anything in the request when searching for "access_token", could that be the problem?

Comment: @AbeBrandsma the postman requests are irrelevant, what's important is the http *response* that has a `Set-Cookie` header, that is what tells the browser to store a cookie and then send it on successive requests to the same domain.

Comment: @AbeBrandsma also redirect codes are in the `3xx` range. Using `http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, 200)` is wrong. If you take a look at the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Redirect) you'll see that is says *"The provided code should be in the 3xx range and is usually StatusMovedPermanently, StatusFound or StatusSeeOther."*.

Comment: @NoamHacker, Which request do you mean exactly? For as far as I know, I do not have to include the name of the cookie in the headers when requesting it, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @mkopriva, good point on the 200 code, I'll change that. I've edited the original question to include those requests.

Comment: @AbeBrandsma cookies are not set by requests, they are set by *responses*. Showing a request dump "when **setting the cookie**" is not helpful. Please show the **response** when **setting the cookie**.

Comment: @mkopriva, so you mean these?

Comment: edit: *moved response headers to original question instead of here*

Comment: @AbeBrandsma yes, that's the relevant `Set-Cookie` response header and it looks like it is indeed correct but, that's the output of `ResponseWriter.Header()` from Go... now you need to make sure that postman also sees the same `Set-Cookie` header in the response, if they do then you know you're setting the cookie properly. Also it's not clear whether that's the response to the `POST /auth/users/login?redirect=/` request or to something else?

Comment: @AbeBrandsma what seems a bit weird is that when you're attempting to log in (`POST /auth/users/login?redirect=/`) you already have the cookie and it is being sent by postman (in the `cookie` header)... while this is not necessarily wrong it makes little sense to try to log in if you're already logged in. Additionally, in the subsequent request (`GET /path/provide`) the cookie is not being sent by postman anymore (there is no `cookie` header) which makes it obvious why you can't see the cookie in your Go app. This does not seem to be a problem with Go's `r.Cookie` but with Postman.

Comment: @AbeBrandsma for example at one point there was an issue with Postman not sending cookies on subsequent requests ([see link](https://community.getpostman.com/t/postman-no-longer-send-cookie-with-subsequent-requests/1723/7)). So make sure you have a version of Postman that does not have this problem. Also make sure that any Postman settings related to cookies are properly set up. Also, while you're testing on your localhost make sure to keep the `Secure` flag set to `false`, a value of `true` will only send the cookie over `https` which in most cases is not the protocol used by localhost.

Comment: @mkopriva, thanks for your help. I tried to switch to another version of Postman (canary), yet this also yields the same error. It was the response to that POST request indeed. I've decided to switch to store the JWT token in local storage.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to set the Path of the cookie:

```
    c := &http.Cookie{Name: name, Value: encode(value), Path: "/"}
    http.SetCookie(w, c)
```

if you don't, the Path will be the path of the current request, and the cookie will therefore ONLY be available from this exact path.

Answer (score 0):

When I was sending `/login` post request from postman, the backend successfully set the cookie and token cookie accompanied subsequent requests. When I was trying the endpoints with React app, the cookies were not set properly and send during subsequent requests. The issue is when cors enabled, we need to pass `credentials: include` during both /login endpoint (the one which set the cookie) and subsequent requests for the cookie to set and send back to server. I was using fetch api which needs `credentials: include` mentioned explicitly if `cors` enabled.

```
// my login request looks like
export async function login(credentials: Credentials) {
  const userRes = await fetch(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT}/login`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    }
  )
  return await userRes.json()
}
// subsequent requests
export async function getCurrentUser() {
  const userRes = await fetch(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT}/userinfo`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }
  )

  return await userRes.json()
}
```

In the backend, we need to specify the origins, as allow all origin is not accepted when using `credentials: 'include'`. Some of the solutions related to this problem suggest to disable `HttpOnly and Secure`. Here is my note from going through the documentation related to HttpOnly and Secure. For my problem, both of them had no credit to the problem.

HttpOnly - ensures the cookie is not accessible to Javascript.

Secure - sends the cookie over https or localhost only.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the cookie by wrong name. Does `config.AccessTokenName == "access_token"?` (I think not). But you are trying to get the cookie with the cookie name `access_token`.

This is an working example code, tested on both POSTMAN and Web browser.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/set", SetTokenAndRedirect)

    http.HandleFunc("/get", getToken)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)

}

func SetTokenAndRedirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r 
*http.Request) {

    expirationTime := time.Now().Add(time.Hour)
// Set the cookie with the JWT
    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "access_token", // you have to search 
the cookie by this name
        Value:    "12378",
        Expires:  expirationTime,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Secure:   false,
    })

    redirectURL := "/"

    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, 200)

}

func getToken(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c, err := r.Cookie("access_token")

    if err != nil {
        if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
            log.Println("Error finding cookie: ", err)
        }
        //handle the error gracefully
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tokenString := c.Value

    log.Println("Cookie found: ", tokenString)

}
```

For further experiment or if needed: Set the headers (including cookies) before anything else is written.

A good discussion is could be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2rkij9/cant_set_a_cookie/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. I'm sorry that I caused some confusion there. I am in fact searching for "access_token" and setting "access_token", I had temporarily changed it for my own sanity check. The discussion you send does help though, I might be writing something to the response before setting the cookies.